# How to get service names with Beam::Wire?

Tags: perl, dependency-injection

I have to reverse engineer one Perl project that use Beam::Wire for dependency injection.

How can I get list of services names ?

Attribute [services](https://metacpan.org/pod/Beam::Wire#services) seems not working.

Here is my code

```
# wire.yml
captain:
    class: Person
    args:
        name: Malcolm Reynolds
        rank: Captain
first_officer:
    $class: Person
    name: Zoë Alleyne Washburne
    rank: Commander

# script.pl
use Beam::Wire;
use Data::Dumper;
my $wire = Beam::Wire->new( file => 'wire.yml' );
my $a = $wire->services;
warn Dumper $a;           # shows $VAR1 = {} but I expected [ 'captain', 'first_officer' ]
```

Comment: Be careful not to use [$a or $b](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$a) outside of sort blocks. They are special global variables, and declaring them as lexicals will break sort blocks in that scope. The easiest way to avoid this is to mentally replace them with `$x` and `$y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `services` attribute is more of a cache as mentioned in the docs. It will not be populated with all services after building the object, only with each service as it's built for a `get` or `set` call. You can pass the `eager` value for a service [lifecycle configuration](https://metacpan.org/pod/Beam::Wire::Help::Config#OBJECT-LIFECYCLE) to cause it to be cached as soon as the object is created.

If you just want a list of all top level services from the configuration file, you can check the keys of the config hash.

```
my @services = keys %{$wire->config};
```

Comment: `keys %{$wire->config}` is actually what I was needed. Thanks a lot!